# Is two single byte random codes more secure than a single word random code?

Tags: probability, random

I am trying to create secret keys for a post so users can edit them without entering password. Typically I use two secret IDs to reference a post,

> ID1=8 byte long random code
>
> ID2=8 byte long random code
>
> The format is like   www.domain.com/post.php?id1=12345678&id2=12345678

Somehow I am thinking using two code is more secure (harder to break) than using a single 16 byte code? Is my assumption correct? Is using two code more secure than a single code, assuming both have the same length? Programatic suggestions are welcome

Comment: Why don't you use only one code but **alpha-numeric** instead? The combinations will increase!

Comment: Please explain why you think dividing 16 bytes into two chunks of 8 bytes would make sequential guessing either easier or harder.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like the time complexity is identical, since there's a unique two-code URL for every one-code URL, and *vice versa*.

Comment: @BruceTrumbo at least I think if someone want to decode the url correctly, they have to decode two string not just one, which could be easier programmatically even though longer in length